# Android Intent to share from web browser

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I am trying to create a share button for Android devices in my web page.

I want to be able to click that button so that an Android device will show you all the applications that allow sending text to someone else.

I found an example of this functionality at [paul.kinlan.me](https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/) and as such created following URL:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;
    action=android.intent.action.SEND;
    type=text/plain;
    S.android.intent.extra.TEXT=http://youreka-virtualtours.be/tours/primo/;
    S.android.intent.extra.SUBJECT=Bekijk%20deze%20virtual%20tour%20van%20Primo%20Restaurant%20Antwerpen;
    end">Share</a>
```

But when clicking it on my Android device, nothing happens. If I add a fallback URL, that does open, so now my question is: doe actually none of the mainstream sharing apps (Facebook, Whatsapp, ...) support this functionality or is there something wrong with the URL I generated?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your browser does not support the `intent` scheme. With regards to your URL, the easiest way to get the right one is to write an Android app, create the `Intent` object in Java code with the specifications that you want, then [use `toUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri%28int%29) to generate the URL.